# Command not working from "command" section in docker compose

Tags: docker-compose

I try to use [php:7.2-apache](https://hub.docker.com/_/php/) to run my (Laravel) code. As we have apache currently on our production server.

However I need the module mod_rewrite to be loaded, which is not the case by default for me.

**docker-compose.yml**

```
  apache:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: php:7.2-apache
    container_name: apache_l
    command: bash -c "a2enmod rewrite && service apache2 restart"
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public/
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./docker/php-ini/php.ini:/usr/local/etc/php/php.ini
    - ./docker/sites-enabled:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/
```

I wrote the command in order to start mod_rewrite as suggested here:
https://github.com/docker-library/php/issues/179

If I run these commands by hand in the container it works, however in a command section like this I get an error log:

> Enabling module rewrite.
>
> To activate the new configuration, you need to run:
>
> service apache2 restart
>
> AH00558: apache2: Could not reliably determine the server's fully
>   qualified domain name, using 192.168.0.3. Set the 'ServerName'
>   directive globally to suppress this message
>
> Restarting Apache httpd web server: apache2.
>
> Module rewrite already enabled
>
> ...

How come it only works when running these commands by hand?

Bonus question: (not that important)
Why does the APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT environment variable not work. I have to change the config inside `:/etc/apache2/sites-enabled/` by hand for it to work, but the variable is advertised.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I fixed it another way by first running

```
docker cp apache_l:/etc/apache2/ .\docker\
```

which will copy the entire config directory to the host and then mounting that directory as a volume in the **docker-compose.yml**

```
apache:
    restart: unless-stopped
    image: php:7.2-apache
    container_name: apache_l
#    depends_on:
#    - openssl
    ports:
    - 80:80
    - 443:443
    environment:
      - APACHE_DOCUMENT_ROOT=/var/www/html/public/
    volumes:
    - .:/var/www/html
    - ./docker/apache2:/etc/apache2/
```

I also made a symlink from **mods-available/rewrite.load** to **mods-enabled/rewrite.load**